# Silverlight 4.0 - how to target Silverlight runtime version for XAP in VS 2010?

Tags: silverlight, version, xap

I have a situation when my XAP is being produced with Silverlight version installed on my dev machine, while users (enterprise company) use a different (earlier) version. Users don't have ability to upgrade their Silverlight runtime due to IT Department policy.

I have no control over when or which version of Silverlight runtime that IT department is going to allow users to have. I know only Silverlight version they use at any given moment.

So the question is how can I build XAP file targeting specific version of Silverlight run time (4.0.50401.0 in my case)? I tried to play with AppManifest file and do some other manipulations inside of VS 2010 but was not lucky with finding solution yet.

I would appreciate if you could advise.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tim Heuer blogged about this, http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2010/09/28/keeping-your-silverlight-dev-environment-stable-through-service-releases.aspx.

Basically he is suggesting you maintain the version of the Silverlight SDK that your users will have on your development machine. This will allow you to build XAPs against that version of the SDK.

Comment: Thanks Jason. I read Tim's post. It is a solution to the problem, although I was hoping to find something in VS 2010 settings to achieve the same without reinstalling of much stuff. I tend to believe that there is no much can be done to control the version except what Tim recommends.

Comment: I was equally surprised that there was not a setting that could be used to control this. All in all, though, the fix does not seem to be that bad, especially since you know what version your users will have.